# How to get specific data from Wikipedia?

Tags: php, query-string, wikipedia-api

I only want to get data that is about Video Games (like [Duke Nukem 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_Nukem_3D), Atari Games, etc.). But looking at how they expect you to query and how others have done it, I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it. I've searched for a couple of days now on how to do it but have come out empty handed.

I also had a look at their API but how they want you to make a query string didn't really help me. I tried to do this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&format=json&titles=Video_Game
```

But it gave me this in return:

```
{
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{
      "normalized":[
         {
            "from":"Video_Game",
            "to":"Video Game"
         }
      ],
      "pages":{
         "361741":{
            "pageid":361741,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Video Game",
            "categories":[
               {
                  "ns":14,
                  "title":"Category:Redirects from other capitalisations"
               },
               {
                  "ns":14,
                  "title":"Category:Unprintworthy redirects"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I suspect it just found me the page for what a Video Game is but not all pages that are about Video Games. I might just not understand correctly how to get data from Wikipedia.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pages in English Wikipedia about video games contain template called [Infobox video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_video_game), so you just need to use [Wikipedia API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Btranscludedin) query with property `transcludedin` to get all them:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=transcludedin&tilimit=500&titles=Template:Infobox_video_game
```

Comment: Oooh Templates. That's the one. Okay. Thanks, that does explain it better!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, [Video Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Video_Game&redirect=no) is a [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Redirect) to [Video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game) (capitalization matters in Wikipedia, except for the very first character of the title) so it does not have much useful information. You can use the `redirects=1` API parameter to automatically resolve redirects.

Another problem is that you are asking the API what categories the video game article is in. What you probably wanted is to ask what articles are in the video game category. That's something like [`action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AVideo+games`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category%3AVideo+games).

The third problem is that categories form a graph, so usually most of the relevant content is in subcategories and not the main category itself. That is the case with [Category:Video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Video_games) as well. So even if you had retrieved the article list correctly, it wouldn't have been particularly useful.

There are various ways to get a more useful list of relevant articles.

- You can query based on infobox inclusion as Termininja said. The problem with that is that it will miss articles which don't have the infobox (generally newer, less well-written ones).
- You can use the experimental, standalone [category graph search service](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Nova_Resource:Catgraph) to find all articles in the video games category and subcategories. In practice that can be dangerous with very generic categories such as "video games" because the category system is messy - it's not a proper tree, it contains loops and other weird things, so you might find that when going deep enough into subcategories the content is not even remotely related to video games. (For example video games > video game culture > nerd culture > anime and manga fandom.)
- You can use [SPARQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) queries with [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page), such as [is a: video game](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ7889%20.%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D). This depends on the Wikidata information being properly maintained, which is not always the case.

You are probably best off using the infobox in this case.

Comment: I tried to follow what Termininja said and then wrote a program to recursively go through all the "continue" segments until I got all of them. I ended up with 22029 entries in the end and then used another query to find the Wiki Base Item ID of each of those entries using their titles. Now I have all the unique identifiers and need to get all the article information with those.

Comment: @Vipar, you can get all Wikidata IDs with your first query: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=transcludedin&prop=pageprops&titles=Template:Infobox_video_game&ppprop=wikibase_item&gtilimit=500 by using generator.

Comment: @Termininja Yeah I tried to understand the whole generator deal but I couldn't make it work so I gave up